# Django - Server error 500 with URL tag

Tags: python, django, url, tags, server-error

I have an issue when I put online my **Django** Project. 
If I have an `{% url ... %}` tag in my main html file (base.html), I see "`Server Error 500`".

If I remove all these lines with `{% url ... %}`, my django website works fine and the "`Server Error 500`" disappears !  I have this issue only with the URL tag.

For information, I have no issue when I work locally (127.0.0.1) on my computer. My hosting (**Alwaysdata.com**) use `python 2.6 and Django 1.6.4`

Could you help me please ? :)

Comment: Can you modify the settings file and put the app into debug mode? That would make figuring out what is doing on much simpler. Also, 1.6.x is deprecated and is no longer receiving security updates do I would update ASAP to at least 1.7.10.

Comment: Check the Error Mails, if you have DEBUG=False.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue by adding `#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the begenning of all my Python `(*.py)` files because it's an old version about python (2.6)

Thank's to all :)